# Failed to deserialize the value from topic. Invalid UTF-8 start byte in ksql Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have created a very simple ksql stream on a kafka topic.

```
CREATE TABLE users_original (EVENT STRUCT<HEADER STRING , BODY STRUCT<gender VARCHAR, region VARCHAR>>) WITH
(kafka_topic='users', value_format='JSON');
```

Stream is created and it is working fine. The data that is coming is as below:

```
{"event":{"header": "v1","body":{"gender":"M", "region":"London"}}}
```

From this stream I have created another stream in which I am processing some data.

Now from the source there is some special character(Â) that is coming in region value due to which ksql stream stops and throws error:

```
{"event":{"header": "v1","body":{"gender":"M", "region":"Âmerica"}}}
```

The error is:

```
caused by com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jsonparseexception invalid utf-8 start byte
```

And now source stream is not running, I am unable to process the data.

Can someone suggest how can this be solved.

One approach that I have tried is instead of reading the data as json format I am reading the data in string format and after that created one more stream in which I am removing special character using REGEX and then again reading the event in JSON format.

This is working fine but in this too many streams are getting created which will impact the performance.

Any other option/approach to handle this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Was the data produced with the regular string serializer, which by default uses utf8? Or have you tried changing the stream encoding?

Comment: yes, With String serializer it was working fine

Comment: Strange that the string serializer would cause an invalid utf8 format. If you can consume from the console outside of ksql, seems like a bug

Comment: @Nikhil can you enter this as an issue on the the ksql GitHub?  https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues